# Exchange server not serving mobile devices - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: exchange-2003, mobile-devices

Our exchange server has suddenly stopped serving mobile devices.  Attempts to connect result in our ActiveSync server returning HTTP 500.

It is serving outlook clients fine.

Our server is Windows 2003 SBS 6.5 SP2

There are no abnormal events in the system log.

I ran the "Exchange ActiveSync with AutoDiscover" at https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

I've notice an abnormality in the exchange properties, Log File Directory shows:

> Access denied.
>
> Facility: Win32 ID no: 80070005
>   Exchange System Manager

As shown in the following image:

[image]

I think it may be related to a recent issue we had here: [Windows server 2003 suddenly unable to connect to anything?](https://serverfault.com/questions/40222/windows-server-2003-suddenly-unable-to-connect-to-anything)

We followed a procedure to reinstall TCP/IP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325356

I've run the "exchange activesync" connectivity test at testexchangeconnectivity.com:

> Attempting to Resolve the host name
>   mail.immersive.com.au in DNS.  Host
>   successfully Resolved Additional
>   Details  IP(s) returned:
>   221.133.203.229
>
> Testing TCP Port 443 on host
>   mail.immersive.com.au to ensure it is
>   listening/open.  The port was opened
>   successfully.
>
> Testing SSL Certificate for validity. 
>   The certificate passed all validation
>   requirements. Test Steps  Validating
>   certificate name  Successfully
>   validated the certificate name
>   Additional Details  Found hostname
>   mail.immersive.com.au in Certificate
>   Subject Common name
>
> Validating certificate trust for
>   Windows Mobile Devices  Certificate is
>   trusted and all certificates are
>   present in chain Additional Details 
>   Certificate is trusted for Windows
>   Mobile 5 and Later platforms. Root =
>   E=server-certs@thawte.com, CN=Thawte
>   Server CA, OU=Certification Services
>   Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc,
>   L=Cape Town, S=Western Cape, C=ZA
>
> Testing certificate date to ensure
>   validity  Date Validation passed. The
>   certificate is not expired. Additional
>   Details  Certificate is valid:
>   NotBefore = 1/5/2009 4:00:00 PM,
>   NotAfter = 1/11/2010 3:59:59 PM
>
> Testing Http Authentication Methods
>   for URL
>   https://mail.immersive.com.au/Microsoft-Server-Activesync/
>   Http Authentication Methods are
>   correct Additional Details  Found all
>   expected authentication methods and no
>   disallowed methods. Methods Found:
>   Basic
>
> Attempting an Activesync session with
>   server  Errors were encountered while
>   testing the ActiveSync session Test
>   Steps  Attempting to send OPTIONS
>   command to server  OPTIONS response
>   was successfully received and is valid
>   Additional Details  Headers received:
>   MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
>   Pragma: no-cache Public: OPTIONS, POST
>   Allow: OPTIONS, POST
>   MS-Server-ActiveSync: 6.5.7638.1
>   MS-ASProtocolVersions: 1.0,2.0,2.1,2.5
>   MS-ASProtocolCommands:
>   Sync,SendMail,SmartForward,SmartReply,GetAttachment,GetHierarchy,CreateCollection,DeleteCollection,MoveCollection,FolderSync,FolderCreate,FolderDelete,FolderUpdate,MoveItems,GetItemEstimate,MeetingResponse,ResolveRecipients,ValidateCert,Provision,Search,Notify,Ping
>   Content-Length: 0 Date: Thu, 16 Jul
>   2009 01:07:27 GMT Server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/6.0 X-Powered-By:
>   ASP.NET
>
> Attempting FolderSync command on
>   ActiveSync session  FolderSync command
>   test failed  Tell me more about this
>   issue and how to resolve it
>
> Additional Details  Exchange
>   Activesync returned an HTTP 500
>   response.**

Could I have some troubleshooting advice?

Comment: Are your ActiveSync devices reporting an error code? Is your SSL certificate up to date?

Comment: You have some bad mojo there. Have you been messing around with NTFS permissions on the system volume or the "\Program Files" directory?

Comment: My iphone is pretty stingy on the error codes... i'll try and get another device.

Also our SSL cert is fine.

Comment: bad mojos indeed - and no recent tinkering with permissions.  thanks evan.

Comment: Ah - the error code is HTTP 500.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd439375.aspx

Comment: odd... are you sure all the web/activesync services are running?  Have there been any changes to the security for the virtual host in IIS?

Comment: What about OWA? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix after two days of troubleshooting this issue is the following article: "The domain name may not appear in its correct form in the DNS record of a Windows 2000-based or Windows Server 2003-based domain controller" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888048

On our SBS 2003 server I then had to: - uninstall the network card from device manager, do a scan for new devices and reinstall it -run "netsh int ip reset" -Reboot the server. -Run the Change Server IP wizard from Server Manager. -Run the connect to internet wizard -Run the remote access wizard.

After doing all of this the server and all features RRAS, Exchange System Manager, Exchange Activesync, RPC over HTTP, etc all work perfectly for me.